# how to calculate i? it's confusing

Tags: java

```
class Test {

    private double d;
    private int i;
    private char c;

    public Test (float x){
        d = x;   
        i = 5;   
        c = 'A';
    }
    public Test (double x){
        d = x + x;   
        i = 3;   
        c = 'Z';
    }

    public void set(char x) { 
        c = x; 
    }

    public void set(int  x) { 
        i = x; 
    }

    public String toString(){ 
        return "d=" + d + " i=" + i + " c ="+c; 
    }

}

public class Display{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Test t1 = new Test(10);
    System.out.println(t1.toString());
    t1.set('m');
    System.out.println(t1);
    Test t2 = new Test(20.25);
    System.out.println(t2);
    t2.set('a' + 1);
    System.out.println(t2);
}
}
```

I don't understand the output of the last command `t2.set('a' + 1);`
the output is:

```
d=40.5 i=98 c =Z"
```

Why is i=98 ?

this is my first time to post here it's telling me my question is mostly code blah blah i'm just adding some text ignoooore it :))))))

Comment: Please don't post nonsense to get around the code/text requirements of the site. Instead please *explain* your code and your problem in greater detail. This is **why** the requirement is in place.

Comment: Also it wouldn't hurt for you to put in a little effort to format that code better so that it makes sense and is easy to read.

Comment: You may want to space out the code a bit better. This will make it easier to read for others.

Answer (score 3):

Because you set it through the `set` method:

```
t2.set('a' + 1);
```

The letter `a` has code point 97. So `'a'+1 == 98`, hence your result. Second, why the `set(int)` overload is selected over the `set(char)` overload, is because `'a' + 1` is obviously of type int: the `'a'` gets promoted to an int and then the addition is performed.

Comment: how can i know letters code points? must i run the code or can i figure it out on paper if i'm in a test ?

Comment: @Muhammad Java characters are `Unicode`, so any Unicode code table will do, e.g. https://unicode-table.com/en/ or http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/index.htm or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters or the definitive source: **https://unicode.org/charts/About.html**